# I made a calculator but it says TypeError: bad operand type or unary -: 'str'

Tags: python, string, typeerror

My code is

---

```
import random
import time
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y
def abv(x):
    if int(x) < 0:
        return -x
    if int(x) >= 0:
        return x
def mul(x, y):
    return str(int(x)*int(y))
def div(x, y):
    return str(int(x)/int(y))
def max(x, y):
    if sx > y:
        return (str(x) + ' is greater than ' + str(y))
    if x < y:
        return (str(y) + ' is graeter than ' + str(x))
    if x == y:
        return 'its the same!'
def min(x, y):
    if x < y:
        return (str(x) + ' is smaller than ' + str(y))
    if x > y:
        return (str(y) + ' is smaller than ' + str(x))
    if x == y:
        return 'its the same!'
while True:
    print(" Welcome to simons calculator!\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('add to add\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('sub to subtract\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('abv for absolute value\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('mul to multiply\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('div to divide\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('max to find out which number is greater\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('min to find out which number is smaller\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x = player = (input("whats your first number? :   "))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    y = player = (input("whats your second number? dont fill this one out if your going for absolute value just hit enter :   "))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    player = input('add sub abv mul div max min? which one? :     ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if player == 'add':
        player = input("your number is " + str(add(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'sub':
        player = input("your number is " + str(sub(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'mul':
        player = input("your number is " + str(mul(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'div':
        player = input("your number is " + str(div(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'max':
        player = input(str(max(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'min':
        player = input(str(min(x,y))+ " enter to continue")
    if player == 'abv':
        player = input("your number is " + str(abv(x))+ " enter to continue")
    else:
        player = input('you made a typo!')
```

---

Everything on this code works just fine, but the abv part doesn't work (absolute value). When I run it and try to calculate absolute value it says TypeError: bad operand type or unary -: 'str' I have been working on this code for couple hours, saw posts from stack overflow but most posts are about +: 'str' not -: 'str'

Comment: It's probably because of `return -x`. You subtract nothing with `x`. If you want to negate the number, you can do `-1*x`

Comment: @Timinator0815  Thanks!